# Multiple files posted on chatter single post in lightning experience

Tags: chatter, lightning

Chatter post in lightning experience allows to post multiple files at a time as shown below
[image]

Now, after the files, I want to query the records and update related parent object, which in my case is "Event" and update the number of total files attached and / or Notes attached. When I am querying 'FeedItem' it is only showing the one record instead of three using the below query

```
SELECT Body
,HasContent
,Id
,ParentId
,RelatedRecordId
,Title
,Type 
FROM FeedItem
```

Where does salesforce keep other child records of file related to a chatter post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the `FeedAttachment` object. See the example towards the bottom of the [documentation page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feedattachment.htm):

```
SELECT Body, (SELECT RecordId, Title, Type, Value FROM FeedAttachments) 
FROM FeedItem 
WHERE Id = 'some_feedItem_id'
```